# How to force the legend inside the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following codes keep generating the legend outside the plot although I think I made a relevant revision. How can I relocate the legend?

```
ftreated = factor(df$treated)

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = hhi, color = ftreated)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = mean) + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = 1997, xmax = 1998, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .25) + 
  scale_color_manual("", labels=c("Treated", "Control"), values = c("red", "black")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual("", labels=c("Treated", "Control"), values = c(1, 1)) + 
  theme(
    legend.title = element_text(size=8),
    legend.text = element_text(size=8),
    legend.direction = "vertical",
    # Set legend.position with numeric values for x and y within the plot area
    legend.position = c(0.2, 0.8),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "#666666"),
    plot.caption = element_text(size=10, family="Times", hjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5)
  ) + 
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(1992, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2008, 2011), 
    limits = c(1992, 2011)
  ) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  ylab("HHI")
```

Comment: Have you tried using `theme_bw()` before the custom `theme()` settings?